# Inline elements in single line

Tags: html, css

I am trying a layout where I need each item in single line. The width of those items is taken from the content inside them. Something like this:

**Expected output:**
(*Works only in modern browsers*)

```css
.item {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
.wrap {
  width: max-content;  /* works only in modern browsers */
  margin: 5px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="item wrap">hello</div><!-- NO SPACE --><div class="item wrap">hey</div>
```

I want to produce the same layout for **IE9+ browsers without altering the HTML**. Assume the parent as `body` tag.

If I use `white-space: pre-line` to the parent element, I can get the result like this:

**Possible close workaround by me:**

```css
.item {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
}
body {
  white-space: pre-line;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="item wrap">hello</div>
<div class="item wrap">hey</div>
```

But in HTML, there is no space between the `.item` elements. So, this won't work.

**Failed workaround because no space between HTML tags:**

```css
.item {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
}
body {
  white-space: pre-line;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="item wrap">hello</div><!-- NO SPACE --><div class="item wrap">hey</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `display: table;` on `.wrap`.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.item {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
.wrap {
  display: table;
  margin: 5px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="item wrap">hello</div><!-- NO SPACE --><div class="item wrap">hey</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT :

solution with `display:table`

let me know if this one does the trick ;)

```css
.item {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: skyblue;
    margin: 5px auto;
   display:table

}
```

```html
<div class="item wrap">hello</div><!-- NO SPACE --><div class="item wrap">hey</div>
```

Comment: @Mr_Green added solution with `display:table` , should work as i know. it works from IE 8 +

Comment: Yeah it works but someone already provided the same solution. So I accepted that. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try to put margin right on wrap but not on the last item. Check this snippet.

```css
.item {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrap:not(:last-child){
  margin-right:10px;
}
body {
  white-space: pre-line;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="item wrap">hello</div><!-- NO SPACE --><div class="item wrap">hey</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to mark the .item divs as inline-blocks if you want them to be in the same line. Marking them as inline-blocks additionally allows you to add padding, margins to them as well.

Also, it would be best to wrap your .items inside a .wrap container.

```css
.item {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
.wrap {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="item">hello</div>
    <div class="item">hey</div>
</div>
```